# Invoke JDialog into Custom JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, super, jdialog, jinternalframe

In a beginning I tested my project in a JFrame, but after I tried to emigrate it to a custom JInternalFrame from another existent project, it gives me a incompatibility error, because a JInternalFrame can not be converted to Frame.

I do the invoke with this:

```
MyJDialog mjd = new MyJDialog(this,false,myobject);
```

Constructor of my JDialog:

```
public MyJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent,boolean modal,Object myobject) {
super(parent,modal); /*This part it's giving me conflict due JInternalFrame can not be converted to Frame*/
//another code
}
```

So, which function can I use to replace "super" or which solution can I apply?

Comment: You could use [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved incompatibilty problem, it seems to be ok when I change parameter in constructor to java.awt.Window, but gives me an error in the running, seems the code need component must be java.awt.Frame, do you know other alternative?

Comment: Forget it. It works perfectly, the problem was in another part of the code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MadProgrammer, the solutions it's as follow:

The invoke:

```
MyJDialog mjd = new MyJDialog(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this),myobject);
```

Constructor of my JDialog:

```
public MyJDialog(java.awt.Window parent,Object myobject) {
    super(parent,"");
    //another code
}
```